# If a sequence is nonincreasing and bounded below, does $a_n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$ where $1$ is a lower bound?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that I know that $a_n\geq a_{n+1}$ and that $a_n>1$ (no other information is known).

Since $a_n$ is nonincreasing and bounded below, then by the monotone convergence theorem, it converges to its infimum. Can I conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$? Well, $1$ is a lower bound so for sure I do not know if it is infimum or not!

Comment: `1 is a lower bound so for sure I do not know if it is infimum or not` Right. Consider for example the constant sequence $a_n = 2\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot conclude this. If a sequence decreases monotonically to any $x > 1$, it will satisfy your conditions and not your conclusion (for example, consider $x_n = 2 + \frac{1}{n}$).

Answer (score 0):

The sequence will converge to the infimum of its range (in the extended real line if the sequence is not bounded below). Hence your claim follows iff $1$ is infact the infimum.